# Show enlarged picture when mouse hover over an image

Tags: html, image

On my webpage, I want to put an image such that when the mouse pointer hovers over that image, an enlarged version will appear.

Comment: all you would have to do is create a rollover image, and when the mouse's location is anywhere over the image, set the frame of the image to however big you want it to be.

Answer (score 8):

Updated CSS solution based on further explanation of the requirement in the comments

http://jsfiddle.net/5sRTX/7/

```
<div class="effectback">
<img class="effectfront" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6873010155_d4160a32a2.jpg" />
</div>

attribution<br/>
https://secure.flickr.com/photos/34022876@N06/6873010155/sizes/m/in/photostream/

.effectback {
  display: block;
  background: url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6873010155_d4160a32a2_s.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectfront {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectfront:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Original css solution based on the original question

CSS solution

http://jsfiddle.net/ERh62/1/

```
.effectscale {
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectscale:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, what I have are two images, one image with lower resolution, and another with higher resolution. I want the lower-resolution image being put in the page, then when user's mouse hover over the image, the high-resolution version is displayed. How to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much. That looks really nice. Is there a way to make the large popup image locate at the same center as the small image?

Answer (score 7):

```
<img src="..." onmouseover="this.width='someWidth'; this.height='someHeight'" onmouseout="this.width='originalWidth'; this.height='originalHeight'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .container{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:300px;/*change this to whatever you want*/
        height:150px;/*change this to whatever you want*/

        /*Of course, to get the desired effect, the size of the image "<img>" below must be larger than the size mentioned above*/
    }

    .container:hover{
        overflow:visible
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'><img src='myImage.png'/></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not use same percentages instead of fixed pixels? Fixed width and height tend to create distorted images as soon as you are working with variable images/dimensions.