# Simple method of enlarging thumbnails on mouse over in a Web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover

My project has pages with many image thumbnails on them. The dimensions are 150x150. We want the site to popup a full size image upon hovering over each thumbnail. I would like to know the easiest way to accomplish this, whether it's using HTML, or JavaScript, or CSS, as well as the basic steps to start playing with it and getting it going.

I am looking for a simple solution keeping in mind that my skill set is some basic JavaScript and HTML, and I am unfamiliar with how CSS works.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456169/show-enlarged-picture-when-mouse-hover-over-an-image

Comment: Your contribution is not very helpful. The examples in the link you provided are very complicated. I asked for a couple simple answers. There is not any instruction as to how to implement it with the rest of my html.

Comment: You have no html shown here.

Comment: Also, Java != Javascript. You probably mean Javascript (correct tag) but say "Java" in your question text.

Comment: @xenosaga01 - We're not going to do the work for you. The question you posted here shows no effort on your part to find a solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the width and height attributes on mouseover, and restoring them on mouseout.

```js
$("img").mouseover(function() {
    this.setAttribute("data-width", this.width);
    this.setAttribute("data-height", this.height);
    this.removeAttribute("width");
    this.removeAttribute("height");
});
$("img").mouseout(function() {
    this.setAttribute("width", this.getAttribute("data-width"));
    this.setAttribute("height", this.getAttribute("data-height"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img height="25" width="25" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a5563b966d383529a65612e6590f957f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

A couple caveats:

1. You don't need jQuery - but I used it here to avoid having to deal with the differences in event models between browsers
2. You probably don't want this to run for every image. In that case, replace the `img` with a class, like `.hoverable`

A more compact version, using more jQuery functions:

```js
$("img").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        'data-width': this.width,
        'data-height': this.height
    }).removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr({
        width: $(this).attr('data-width'),
        height: $(this).attr('data-height')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img height="25" width="25" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a5563b966d383529a65612e6590f957f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look into using a library like lightbox (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
or jquery zoom (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)