# Switching between preview (small) and enlarged images html/css and having only one on screen at a time

Tags: html, css, image

I'm fairly new to html/css. I have a bit of code I'm wondering if you guys can help me modify. So. I'm working on a gallery where I am cropping the images by making them the background of a table (simplified to two columns, it's actually a 3x3 grid):

```
<table cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="275px" height="200px" align="center" background="images/kitchen/1.jpg"></td>
            <td width="275px" height="200px" align="center" background="images/kitchen/2.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is either have the full images popup on mouse hover or have the image blow up on mouse hover where the other images would be pushed out of the way naturally (where the image would alternate to the full size and back on mouse contact/removal)

A helpful bit of code I was able to find was this one but I can't figure out how to make it work with the table and I also don't know how to make the "Required text" field disappear when I roll over it with the mouse.

html:

```
<a href="#">Required text<img src="image url" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
a img { display:none; }
a:hover img { display:block; }
```

A couple noob questions but thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show enlarged picture when mouse hover over an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456169/show-enlarged-picture-when-mouse-hover-over-an-image)

Comment: ^that worked great thanks McVenco!